# How do you perform service-oriented parent-child transactions?

Tags: web-services, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, breeze, graphdiff

> #### Example:
>
> A SalesOrder is composed of a SalesOrderHeader and one or more SalesOrderItems. When editing an existing SalesOrder, the SalesOrderHeader can be modified and SalesOrderItems can be added, modified and deleted. All changes must be saved in a single transaction. Multiple users may edit the SalesOrder at the same time with optimistic concurrency.

I believe that the requirement to have the save done in a single transaction encourages us to communicate both the SaleOrderHeader and the SalesOrderItems in a single service call. The implication of packaging up the child data with its parent is that there will need to be some understanding as to whether the child data is added, modified or deleted.

Change tracking of the child entities can happen either on the server or on the client.

### Change tracking on the server

The idea with this strategy is that the client can modify the SalesOrder to its will without tracking which SalesOrderItems are added, modified or deleted. The state of the SalesOrderItems will be determined on the server when the save service is called.

The server should remain stateless between service calls. This means that the server can’t retain any information about the state of the SalesOrder between its retrieval and its eventual save. The only option left if for the server to determine the state of its entities by comparing the modified object graph to the database object graph.

With nHibernate, there is a merge function to accomplish this. With Entity framework, the [highest voted feature request](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/864) is to have this added. There’s also an open source implementation of this for EF called [GraphDiff](https://github.com/refactorthis/GraphDiff).

This sounds great in theory because it makes the services very easy to design and use. However, I see two major issues with this strategy. The first is performance. The entire object graph must be sent back on every save. Whether or not a SalesOrderItem was modified, it must be sent back or the server will assume it’s been deleted. The second problem is even more critical and it has to do with concurrency. If User 1 adds a SalesOrderItem to a SalesOrder and User 2 makes a change to the same SalesOrder, when User 2 saves the server will assume that the SalesOrderItem added by User 1 should be deleted because it was not included in User 2’s object graph. I don’t see a way this can be prevented in any implementation of server side change tracking.

### Change tracking on the client

The alternative is to have the client track changes to its entities and communicate that state when calling the save service. One benefit is that the client does not need to send its unchanged child entities. This helps with performance. A downside is that all entities will need an additional property named something along the lines of “ObjectState” to track whether it’s added, modified or deleted. This makes the entity models on the server quite messy and filled with concerns unrelated to the business domain. This also puts onus on the different consumers of the service to maintain this state. Another problem is that it becomes difficult to deal with deleted entities. Should the SalesOrderHeader maintain a list of deleted SalesOrderItems? or should the SalesOrderItems get assigned a state of deleted which must be filtered out by the client UI?

I know that [breeze](http://www.breezejs.com/) javascript library has its own implementation of client-side entity tracking but my concern is that its implementation requires both client-side and server-side components. Shouldn't the service layer isolate which technology we use on either side? What if non-javascript clients want to use my services?

### Question

I would think this is a common scenario that should be addressed by the majority of service implementations. Have I made any incorrect assumptions or am I doing anything out or the ordinary? What strategy have you implemented? Are there any reasonable alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full disclosure: I work with [Breeze](http://www.breezejs.com/), and I think change tracking on the client is the way to go.  Change tracking on the client allows stateless servers, reduces traffic between the client and server, and allows offline use.

In Breeze, the "ObjectState" that you mention is called the [EntityAspect](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/inside-entity), and each entity has one, but it is not part of the domain model.  The server-side entities don't need an EntityAspect, but the server-side service has to know how to handle the entity state information that comes from the client.

Basically, the service needs to create, update, or delete entities based on the information coming from the client.  There are existing server-side backends for Breeze that do all this already (in [.NET (EF and NHibernate)](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.server.net), [Java](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.server.java), [PHP](https://github.com/adrotec/breeze.server.php), [Node](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.server.node), and [Ruby](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/tree/master/ruby/CCJS-Ruby)), but you can also write your own.  Your server just needs to know how to talk to the client.

Let's say we've updated a `SalesOrder` and added a new `SalesOrderItem`.  The Breeze client sends a save bundle that looks something like this:

```
{
"entities": [
    {
        "Id": 123,
        "Title": "My Updated Title",
        "OrderDate": "2014-08-03T07:00:00.000Z",
        "entityAspect": {
            "entityTypeName": "SalesOrder:#My.DomainModel",
            "entityState": "Modified",
            "originalValuesMap": {
                "Title": "My Original Title"
            },
            "autoGeneratedKey": {
                "propertyName": "Id",
                "autoGeneratedKeyType": "Identity"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Id": -1,
        "SalesOrderId": 123,
        "ProductId": 456,
        "Quantity": 11,
        "entityAspect": {
            "entityTypeName": "SalesOrderItem:#My.DomainModel",
            "entityState": "Added",
            "originalValuesMap": {
            },
            "autoGeneratedKey": {
                "propertyName": "Id",
                "autoGeneratedKeyType": "Identity"
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

Here, SalesOrder with Id# 123 has been modified (its Title has been changed).  The `entityAspect` includes the `originalValuesMap` which shows what the previous Title was.
The server would need to update the existing SalesOrder with the new value.  Whether the server needs to query the existing SalesOrder from the database before applying the changes is implementation-dependent.

A new SalesOrderItem has been added.  A temporary Id, -1, was created for it on the client.  The server needs to create and persist a new SalesOrderItem and generate a real Id for it.

The response from the server should contain the entities that were created and updated, and KeyMapping information that shows what server-generated keys map to the temporary client-side keys, so that the client can replace them.

Change tracking is not a simple problem, but Breeze tries to do the hard parts for you.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer because I will be using Breeze as my solution. I was hoping to find a solution that felt a little more RESTful but I don't think REST is really meant to deal with multiple entities at once. Breeze seems to solve my exact problem in a way that's pretty slick. Thanks for the detailed response and keep up the good work!

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to piggy back on Steve's answer.

We should be clear: the onus for implementing the Order-graph (AKA "Order aggregate") transaction in a relational data model falls on the developer. BreezeJS (and Breeze helpers for .NET servers) can facilitate but you have to make it work.

The key to making this work is including the root element of the aggregate - the Order - in all changes to any entity within the aggregate. If you add, delete, or modify an OrderItem, **make sure you modify the Order at the same time** .

How? By bumping the Order's concurrency property (e.g, the `rowVersion`) and making sure that Breeze KNOWS this is your concurrency property.

> You must implement root entity optimistic concurrency if you want to ensure Order aggregate consistency.

Now you can detect if someone else has made a change to any part of the Order aggregate. That could be a change to the Order or an add/mod/delete of one of its OrderItems.

**You do not have to include all OrderItems in the change-set when you save a changed Order aggregate. You only need to include the OrderItems that are added/modified/deleted.**

Of course some other user may make a change to the Order aggregate before you save yours. When you try to save yours, the save will fail with an optimistic concurrency error.

**Upon detecting an optimistic concurrency error for an Order, make sure the client removes the entire order aggregate from cache - the Order and all of its OrderItems - and then re-fetch the aggregate** Don't just re-fetch the root Order entity and start messing with its items. Make sure you remove the entire aggregate from cache and then re-fetch it (the order and its items).

If everyone follows this protocol you'll be in fine shape on the server.

Comment: I assume there are parent-child scenarios where you want to ensure aggregate consistency and others where you don't. For example a Profile can have many PictureAttachments. You may want to allow multiple users to add/modify/delete PictureAttachments at the same time. Another user's changes should not affect your decision/ability to make your own changes. In a scenario like this I assume you would leave the Profile's rowVersion unchanged. The decision to ensure consistency over the object graph needs to be decided case by case. Is this correct?

Comment: Well not precisely. The nature of an aggregate is that it is really one thing *represented relationally* by multiple entities in parent/child relationships.  Not all entities in parent/child relationships are aggregates. For example, Customer/Orders is usually not. It's a domain decision whether a graph is or isn't an aggregate. Even then it can be difficult to decide whether the object graph is or is not an aggregate. All that said, I agree that many object graphs do NOT have consistency requirements of this kind and you should not implement master/slave optimistic concurrency in those cases.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I think I understand the concept but am fumbling through the terminology.